# chattr +i: chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags

Tags: files, permissions

I am trying to set an immutable attribute on some files that are in my home directory. But I keep getting:

```
chattr +i test.txt
chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on test.txt
```

but when I do:

```
sudo chattr +i test.txt
```

it works.
Is this by design or am I doing something wrong? Internet guides are full of running the `chattr` without sudo.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`chattr` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html):

> A file with the `i` attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file.   **Only  the  superuser  or  a
> process possessing the `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` capability can set or clear this attribute.**

The same applies to the `a` flag (append only), and the `j` flag (data journaling) requires the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability.

So getting an error when trying to se the `i` flag as a regular user is expected.

There are some other flags that don't require privileges to set, not that I'm sure there are too many useful ones. (E.g. the `s` (safe deletion) and `u` (undeletion) flags can be set by any user, they're just not honored by the filesystem...)